# What sightseeing activities are available in winter in the Rocky Mountains?

Tags: usa, planning, national-parks

I will be in NYC in the first week of January. Since I prefer sightseeing and not doing classical winter activities ([ski etc](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.myrockymountainpark.com/.amp/things-to-do/winter-activities-rocky-mountains)), I wonder what sightseeing activities are available in winter in the Rocky Mountains?

Comment: I edited the opinion based and wanta parts out of the question. We don't do recommendations nor travel plans here on travel.se.

Comment: ... hopefully you're aware that the Rocky Mountains are on the other side of the continent from New York City, 2500+ kilometers away?

Comment: @HenningMakholm lol yes I'll take a flight to Denver. Obviously.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from going to a ski resort and admiring the vista from the lodge. This question might be better-received, for example, if you indicate what you expect to get out of sightseeing, and why you are interested in the Rockies as opposed to the Sierra Nevada or the Cascades, and other such details that indicate that the interest is more than a whim.

Answer (score 2):

**Skip it this time**

Unless you are interested in skiing, there are limited activities, and you will miss *a lot.*

All the major national parks (Rocky Mountain NP, Yellowstone, Grand Teton, Glacier etc) will be **closed** or partly closed. As will many hotels, most scenic roads/passes and so on. You can look for individual information about each park and its surroundings [here](https://www.nps.gov/).

The majority of this infrastructure will be closed until April (or later).

However, you can try to visit some alternative destinations, like Las Vegas, Grand Canyon, and some of Utah's national parks (which will be open), like [Zion](https://www.nps.gov/zion/index.htm) or [Arches](https://www.nps.gov/arch/planyourvisit/hours.htm).